# High notes in the mix voice

Tags: technique, voice

When singing high notes, is mixed voice the same thing as head voice? Is mixed voice just a bridge between head and chest, and when you sing higher, it is actually your head voice?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the subject, but as far as I know, head and chest voice are very different in every scenario.

Typically, you want to transition from chest into head voice as you go higher, and vice versa, to avoid straining or damaging your vocal chords.

Mixed voice essentially mixes the two, acting as a bridge. When fully developed, it combines the best of both worlds and makes your delivery super smooth and eliminates breaks from your vocal range.